# Book Recommendation: Multiple variables calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

What would be a good book learning Multiple variables calculus?

Basically, I'm only interested with the theorems of continuity and differentiation

Comment: Why would you not care about integration of functions in several variables?

Comment: It just not part of our course (Calculus II). I don't mind if there will be a chapter about integration :)

Comment: So if you are *in* a course, what is the text for the course?

Comment: Possible lists of duplicates: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus+reference-request), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus+book-recommendation), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus+reference-request+book-recommendation).

Comment: For an inexpensive summary try Schaum's Outline of Calculus, 5th ed.  We use Essentials Calculus, Early Transcendentals by Stewart, ISBN-13: 978-0538497398.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multidimensional Real Analysis I: Differentiation (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics)  by J. J. Duistermaat

[http://www.amazon.com/Multidimensional-Real-Analysis-Differentiation-Mathematics/dp/0521551145/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1421214663&sr=1-7&keywords=duistermaat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521551145)